# Generate pkpass files in Linux

Tags: ios, passbook

I'm trying to generate .pkpass files with this https://github.com/kyleroche/iOS6-passbook-helper

The .pkpass is correctly generated and it also works on iOS 6, but is not working on iOS 7. I've read that it may have something to do with the "signature signing date" as now in iOS 7 is mandatory. Can someone help me to update my .sh so it can create valid .pkpasses for iOS 7 also?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Could you post the pkpass file?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxLdAoSAIoNZU2lHT2pIZVVITVk/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: @MarBVI your quest became pretty much less since you removed the code?! could you post it again somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a quick look at this script and it seems that it is not including the [Apple WWDR Certificate](http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer).

Download the WWDR certificate and convert it to PEM format:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in AppleWWDRCA.cer -out AppleWWDRCA.pem
```

then try adjusting line 61 of the script to include it in the signature:

```
openssl smime -binary -sign -signer certificate.pem -inkey key.pem -passin pass:simplepassword -in "$2/manifest.json" -out "$2/signature" -outform DER -certfile "/path_to/AppleWWDRCA.pem"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @PassKit!! I let you here the new implementation [link](https://github.com/kyleroche/iOS6-passbook-helper/tree/develop)